# APEX - Create chart via "group by" query

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

Using the query

```
SELECT TRUCK_CLASS, COUNT(1) FROM TIC_TRUCK GROUP BY TRUCK_CLASS
```

I can display, in the SQL Commands console, a table that sums all the elements from the column `TRUCK_CLASS` by name.

For example, if my table is something like:

```
Name   - Class 

Entry1 - Heavy
Entry2 - Light
Entry3 - Heavy
```

The query returns:

```
Name  - Count(1)

Heavy - 2
Light - 1
```

How can I turn this into an APEX chart to display a visual representation of the quantities?

For example a pie chart displaying a 33% / 66% value, or a vertical chart, the type does not matter (as long as i can see that one class category is bigger than another). The goal is to display this chart on a page region in an application.

Comment: As I understand, your question is about Oracle APEX. Use tag "oracle-apex", because "apex" is completely another thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, create region with type "Chart" and write your query as

```
SELECT null, TRUCK_CLASS, COUNT(1) 
  FROM TIC_TRUCK 
 GROUP BY TRUCK_CLASS
```

First column is for links (APEX creates link, which you can follow if you click chart), second - for group names, and third - for values.

Comment: How to add two condition here for the TRUCK_BRAND and STATE (columns are in same table TIC_TRUCK) like "where TRUCK_BRAND= "TOYO" and (STATE_ID='1' or STATE_ID='15' );